# jQuery - select DOM elements that have "hidden" attribute in an each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I need to select all `<select>` elements that have a 'hidden' attribute added to them. This is the mark-up:

```
<optgroup label="Label 1">
    <option value="978" hidden>Option 1</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 2</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 3</option>
    <option value="987">Option 4</option>
</optgroup>
```

I'm showing only one `<optgroup>`, but there are many of them in the markup.

So far I have come up with this code:

```
jQuery('optgroup').each(function() {
    var options = jQuery(this).find('option');
    jQuery.each(options, function(index, value) {
        if ($(value).data('hidden') !== undefined) {
            console.log('Found it!');
        }
   });
});
```

Unfortunately, the code conditional inside is never true. What am I missing here?

Comment: you're using `.data('hidden')` when you don't have a `data-hidden` attribute.  You only have a `hidden` attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [attribute exists selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) - the below selector will iterate through all `option` elements which has the `hidden` attribute and is a descendant of `optgroup` element

```
jQuery('optgroup option[hidden]').each(function () {
    console.log('Found it!', this);
});
```

---

Keeping your structure

```
jQuery('optgroup').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('option').each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is('[hidden]')) {
            console.log('Found it!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've changes my question a bit since I made one mistake. Of course I want to find all `option` elements, not `select`. I'd also like to stick to the setup I presented since I'll later be pushing found elements (`value`) into a separate array, hiding `optgroup` if all `option` elements are hidden.

Comment: @luqo33 So is that the end goal of what you're trying to do?  Check to see if all options are hidden and hide the optgroup?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ exactly this. But at this point it comess down to coming up with the right conditional to use in place of the one that I wrote.

Comment: @Arun Suprrisingly, I get 'undefined is not a function' on `.is()`.

Comment: @luqo33 sorry `jQuery(this).is('[hidden]')`

Answer (score 1):

You're issue is that you're checking for a data attribute when you are really using an actual (invalid)attribute

I don't think you need to loop at all though to do what you want.  You can simply use a [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to get all optgroups that satisfy a certain condition.

```
var optgroupsWithAllHiddenOptions = jQuery('optgroup').filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).find('option[hidden]').length == jQuery(this).find('option').length;
});
```

or simply just

```
jQuery('optgroup').filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).find('option[hidden]').length == jQuery(this).find('option').length;
}).hide();
```

```js
jQuery('optgroup').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('option[hidden]').length == $(this).find('option').length;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <optgroup label="Label 1">
    <option value="978" hidden>Option 1</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 2</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 3</option>
    <option value="987">Option 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Label 2">
    <option value="978" hidden>Option 1</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 2</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 3</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Label 3">
    <option value="978" hidden>Option 1</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 2</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 3</option>
    <option value="987">Option 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Label 4">
    <option value="978" hidden>Option 1</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 2</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 3</option>
    <option value="987" hidden>Option 4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: This is a very neat way to do it. Great answer!